# Comparing two different test for continuity -are both methods equivalent?

Tags: limits, continuity

I have a question about determining the continuity of a function.

Previously I have learned that a function $f$ is continuous if

1. $f(a)$ is defined
2. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exist (and here we often need to check to see that the left limit and right limit is the same.
3. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$

But now, my current professor tells us to use the (roughly translated) *continuity condition*. He is surely right, but I can't tell if it's equivalent to the 3 conditions above, or a different 'test'. Here's the condition:

$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} f(a + \Delta x) = f(a) \textbf{ or } \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} f(a + \Delta x)-f(a) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \Delta y = 0   
$$

**Context:** We are supposed to check if the function i continuous on it's Domain.

I can see that there are many similarities to the two methods, but maybe someone can explain further.

**My question is:** Assuming both methods are equivalent, how does the second method fulfill the 3 requirements listed above?

Comment: Your "continuity condition" (at least under its first form) is the same as your condition 3. The latter may be considered as implicitely containing conditions 1. and 2.

Comment: Thanks. Care to expand a bit more? I don't see it.

Comment: What don't you see? My 1st sentence or my 2nd one?

Comment: Second sentence (i.e condition 1 and 2).

Comment: Condition 3 may be considered as implicitely containing conditions 1 and 2, because asserting $A=B$ presupposes that $A$ and $B$ exist.